# get the next tensor from dataset in a tf.while_loop

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to iterate through a dataset until certain condition is met, but I don't know how to "iterate". Below is my code.

```
import tensorflow as tf

c = tf.constant([1,2,6])
d = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((c,))
t = d.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

def condition(t):
  return t < 5

def body(t):
  # I don't know what to do here to return the next t
  return [t]

t = tf.while_loop(condition, body, [t])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run([t]))
```

In response to Alex's answer below, below is a more realistic example of what I want to achieve.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# I want to "merge" the dataset da to dataset db by "backfilling" da.
# So session.run will return [[1,'a'], [1,'x']], then [[5, 'c'],[3, 'y']]
# note that one element from dataset da is skipped, which is what I want to achieve with the while loop.
ta = tf.constant([1,2,5]) 
va = tf.constant(['a','b','c'])
da = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((ta, va))

tb = tf.constant([1,3,6])
vb = tf.constant(['x','y','z'])
db = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tb, vb))

ea = da.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
eb = db.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

def condition(ea, eb):
  return ea[0] < eb[0]

def body(ea, eb):
  # I don't know what to do here to get the next ea.
  return ea, eb

result = tf.while_loop(condition, body, (ea, eb))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run([result])
```

I could move the while loop logic to python as Alex suggested, but I'm guessing leaving it in the dataflow graph will have better performance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you do not understand how Tensorflow works, yet. The Tensorflow [tf.while_loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) creates a while loop inside the computational graph, by adding control statements to reapply parts of the graph multiple times until a certain condition is met. I would advise to start reading [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graphs) to learn about what graphs and sessions are.

You certainly do not want to iterate over your dataset inside the computational graph, the iteration you want is supposed to happen within Python, not the Tensorflow graph.

This is how you would do that:

```py
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

for i in range(100):
  value = sess.run(next_element)
```

This is explained in more detail [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets).

Comment: thanks Alex! I agree with you. I updated my question to make my intention clearer.

Comment: I still do not agree that you should do it that way. But anyways if you really want to, it won't work like that, because [`make_one_shot_iterator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#make_one_shot_iterator) returns a Python iterator, not a tensor. You can not iterate over it inside a Tensorflow graph, it is impossible. If you really want to try something like that you need a different solution, like the one suggested by [Vipin Pillai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895207/vipin-pillai) maybe.

Comment: @AlexanderHarnisch I haven't tested it yet but it seems that it is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237486/tf-data-iterator-get-next-how-to-advance-in-tf-while-loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Dataset.filter()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#filter) method to filter dataset elements according to user-defined predicate.  You have to pass in a filter function which returns a tf.bool tensor which evaluates to true if you want to retain the record or false otherwise.